# How to transfer the apk file on the cloud server to the Android device and install it successfully？

Tags: android

I plan to put the apk file on the cloud server and write a new launcher program myself, which only loads the icon of the cloud application. Click the icon to get the corresponding apk file from the cloud and transfer it to the Android system /data/ app folder and install normally. But the socket is connected, and there is insufficient permission when writing.

I configured ndroid:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the xml file of the launcher program, and wrote LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform in the mk file. But the permissions are still insufficient. I don’t know how to write it, or my method is wrong. Please give me some advice.